# Looking for ways to start new tmux section when server machine starts

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, strongloop

I am looking for a way to do the following when server machine starts

1. start **tmux**
2. **cd /xxx_server directory**
3. run **node ./server/server.js**

I am doing auto-scaling for my APP server and don't want to be going into each server that auto-scaling provision to run the command.

Your advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tmux supports a '-c' option that allows you to pass commands to run once it opens:

```
tmux -c "cd /xxx_server directory && node ./server/server.js"
```

Throw that or something similar to that in a startup script to run at near the end of boot.

Comment: Thanks man. But is there a way to start autostart tmux when server machine starts?

Comment: I used the below in the user data section of EC2, but saying it cannot find the directory I indicated. The directory exist and I start tmux in this directory.  **line 2: cd: xxx_server: No such f $ failed to connect to server**    any advice                                                                             #!/bin/bash
cd my_directory && tmux -c 'node ./server/server.js'
tmux detach
yum update -y